# How to dim the body from navbar hover HTML CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My current layout is this:
[image: Current Layout]
Say I want to dim the entire body when I hover over "More Info" in the navbar and show some information on the newly dimmed body, over everything that was there before; how would I go about doing that?

Everything I have found so far seems to use the fact that what you are trying to dim is the child of what you are hovering over, but if what I am hovering over is a navbar list item, I don't think I can do that, because I will need paragraphs to write the information I want to display.
My Code is as follows:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Pupillometer</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="hide.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Product">Product</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li class = "More"><a href="#"><div class="Para"></div>More Info</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="Moreinfo">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  color: white;
  font: arial sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url('https://source.unsplash.com/K2tdx2mFDHc/1600x900') no-repeat center center/cover;;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  top:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  justify-content: center;
}

.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar ul li {
  margin: 0 1rem;
  padding: 1.5rem;
}
.navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  transition: color 0.25s ease-in;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: skyblue;
}
.navbar ul li.More:hover a {
  color: red;
}
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
}

section h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
}

section p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

```
.Moreinfo {
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top: 60px;
  display:none;
  margin:0 auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
.navbar ul li.More:hover + .Moreinfo{
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us your code, what till now you have tried ? I can help you.

Comment: Added my HTML Code!

Comment: Also, I've tried doing .navbar ul li.More:hover + .navbar {background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);} and other things similar

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and edit your question accordingly. Code relevant to your problem belongs directly into your question, in text form and properly formatted. Don’t show _images of_ code.

Comment: _“Also, I've tried doing .navbar ul li.More:hover + .navbar {background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);} and other things similar”_ - that makes little sense to begin with. `+` is the _adjacent sibling combinator_, meaning it selects an element that is a sibling following another element. Your `.navbar` element is not a sibling of `.navbar ul li.More:hover`, not even close.

Comment: Below I have added answer for you with codepen link. Just updated your code and made it work. Please have look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( '.More' ).hover(function() {
   $( '.Moreinfo' ).toggleClass( "show" );
});
```

Please check below link for exact what you want.

Please follow my [codepen](https://codepen.io/pgurav/pen/eYYXLvd) link

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking to show a div on hover.

Here is what I have tried. Please have a look at the code.

```css
body{
  background-color:lightblue;
  color:white;
}
.more_info{
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
 display:none;
  margin:0 auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}
h1{
  cursor:pointer;
}
h1:hover + .more_info{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>More info</h1>
  <div class="more_info">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can even add more listeners.

Comment: I tried incorporating that, but it doesn't display the more_info. I've tried playing with z-index, but nothing is happening when I hover over my "More Info"... I've uploaded my code, maybe you can find an error? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have done something using jquery. This may be helpful.

```js
$( '.navbar .more' ).hover(function() {
  $( '.moreinfo' ).toggleClass( "show" );
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  color: white;
  font: arial sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url('https://source.unsplash.com/K2tdx2mFDHc/1600x900') no-repeat center center/cover;;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
.navbar {
  position: sticky;
  top:0;
  z-index: 99999;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
  justify-content: center;
}

.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar ul li {
  margin: 0 1rem;
  padding: 1.5rem;
}
.navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  transition: color 0.25s ease-in;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: skyblue;
}
.navbar ul li.More:hover a {
  color: red;
}
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
}

section h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
}

section p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.moreinfo {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.7);
  padding: 15px;
}

.show {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Pupillometer</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="hide.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Product">Product</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="more"><a href="#"><div class="Para"></div>More Info</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="moreinfo">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. Where would I put the First snippet of code ($(#more-info)) etc..?

Comment: @bigfeetman put it inside your external JS file or inside footer tags.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in css

```
.dim {
height:100%;
width:100%;
position:fixed;
left:0;
top:0;
z-index:1 !important;
background-color:black;
filter: alpha(opacity=75); /* internet explorer */
-khtml-opacity: 0.75;      /* kht`enter code here`ml, old safari */
  -moz-opacity: 0.75;      /* mozilla, netscape */
       opacity: 0.75;      /* fx, safari, opera */
}
```

Then add the "dim" class to the body while listening the navigation hover

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and the way I use for my web apps is adding this value in my navbar class
.navbarclass{
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.1)
}
the last value can be anything between 0.1 to 0.9

0.1 lightest
0.9 darkest